# MongoDB combining group aggregation and strLenBytes

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I've a Mongo collection with documents like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a9d0d44c3a1ce5f14c6940a"),
    "topic_id" : "5a7af30613b79405643e7da1",
    "value" : "VMware Virtual Platform",
    "timestamp" : "2018-03-05 09:26:25.136546",
    "insert_ts" : "2018-03-05 09:26:25.136682",
    "inserted_by" : 1
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a9d0d44c3a1ce5f14c69409"),
    "topic_id" : "5a7af30713b79479f82b4b84",
    "value" : "VMware, Inc.",
    "timestamp" : "2018-03-05 09:26:25.118931",
    "insert_ts" : "2018-03-05 09:26:25.119081",
    "inserted_by" : 1
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a9d0d44c3a1ce5f14c69408"),
    "topic_id" : "5a7af30713b7946d6d0a8772",
    "value" : "Phoenix Technologies LTD 6.00 09/21/2015",
    "timestamp" : "2018-03-05 09:26:25.101624",
    "insert_ts" : "2018-03-05 09:26:25.101972",
    "inserted_by" : 1
}
```

I would like to fetch some aggregated data from this collection. I want to know the oldest timestamp, the documents count and the total strlen of all values, but grouped by topic_id, where the document-id is greater than x.

In mysql, i would build a sql like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    MAX(_id) as max_id,
    COUNT(*) as message_count,
    MIN(timestamp) as min_timestamp,
    LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(value)) as size
FROM `dev_topic_data_numeric` 
WHERE _id > 22000
GROUP BY topic_id
```

How do i achieve this in MongoDB? I already tried to build it looking like this:

```js
db.getCollection('topic_data_text').aggregate(
[
    {
        "$match": 
        {
            "_id": {"$gte": ObjectId("5a9d0aefc3a1ce5f14c68c81") }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": 
        {
            "_id": "$topic_id",
            "max_id": {"$max":"$_id"},
            "min_timestamp": {"$min": "$timestamp"},
            "message_count": {"$sum": 1},
            /*"size": {"$strLenBytes": "$value" }*/
        }
    } 
]
);
```

Then i uncomment `$strLenBytes` it crashes saying, that strLenBytes is not a group operator. The [API of MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenBytes/#exp._S_strLenBytes) does not help me here. How do i have to write it to get the strlen?

My expected result should look like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : "5a7af30613b79405643e7da1",
    "max_id" : ObjectId("5a9d0d44c3a1ce5f14c6940a"),
    "min_timestamp" : "2018-03-05 09:26:25.136546",
    "message_count" : 1,
    "size" : 23,
}
```

My MongoDB version is 3.4.4.

Comment: can you add expected output?

Comment: Have you tried `"size": { "$sum": {"$strLenBytes": "$value" } }`?

Comment: @RahulSharma Done.

Comment: @chridam i checked your suggestion. The resulting error says "invalid operator $strLenBytes"

Comment: The closest result i got was using {"$push":"$value"} ... but it's not exactly the result i want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `$strLenBytes` is not an accumulator, unlike `$sum` or `$max`. The `$group` stage accumulates values, so any operator that is valid in the `$group` stage are typically accumulators.

`$strLenBytes` converts one value to another in a 1-1 fashion. This is typically an operator for the `$project` stage.

Adding a `$project` stage in your aggregation should give you the result you require. Note that you would also need to modify the `$group` stage slightly to pass on the required values:

```
> db.test.aggregate([
     {
         "$match":
         {
             "_id": {"$gte": ObjectId("5a9d0aefc3a1ce5f14c68c81") }
         }
     },
     {
         "$group":
         {
             "_id": {"topic_id": "$topic_id", value: "$value"},
             "max_id": {"$max":"$_id"},
             "min_timestamp": {"$min": "$timestamp"},
             "message_count": {"$sum": 1}
         }
     },
     {
         "$project":
         {
             "_id": "$_id.topic_id",
             "max_id": "$max_id",
             "min_timestamp": "$min_timestamp",
             "message_count": "$message_count",
             size: {"$strLenBytes": "$_id.value" }
         }
     }
 ])
```

Output using your example documents:

```
{
  "_id": "5a7af30613b79405643e7da1",
  "max_id": ObjectId("5a9d0d44c3a1ce5f14c6940a"),
  "min_timestamp": "2018-03-05 09:26:25.136546",
  "message_count": 1,
  "size": 23
}
{
  "_id": "5a7af30713b79479f82b4b84",
  "max_id": ObjectId("5a9d0d44c3a1ce5f14c69409"),
  "min_timestamp": "2018-03-05 09:26:25.118931",
  "message_count": 1,
  "size": 12
}
{
  "_id": "5a7af30713b7946d6d0a8772",
  "max_id": ObjectId("5a9d0d44c3a1ce5f14c69408"),
  "min_timestamp": "2018-03-05 09:26:25.101624",
  "message_count": 1,
  "size": 40
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem and it also helped me understanding the project-stagea little more. The documentation is in my opinion lacking a deeper explanation about it's purpose and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

After testing @kevin-adistambha's answer and some further experimenting, I found another way to achieve my wanted result - and maybe it has a better performance - but that needs more testing to be sure about this.

```js
db.getCollection('topic_data_text').aggregate(
[
    {
        "$match": 
        {
            "_id":  {"$gt": ObjectId("5a9f9d8bd5de3ac75f8cc269") }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": 
        {
            "_id": "$topic_id",
            "max_id": {"$max":"$_id"},
            "min_timestamp": {"$min": "$timestamp"},
            "message_count": {"$sum": 1},
            "size": {"$sum": {"$strLenBytes": "$value"}}
        }
    }
]
);
```

Comment: The aggregation pipeline also performs optimization for certain sequence of stages: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/